# Ambiguous call when recursively calling variadic template function overload

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, overload-resolution

Consider this piece of code:

```
template<typename FirstArg>
void foo()
{
}

template<typename FirstArg, typename... RestOfArgs>
void foo()
{
    foo<RestOfArgs...>();
}

int main()
{
    foo<int, int, int>();
    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile due to ambiguous call `foo<RestOfArgs...>();` when `RestOfArgs` has only one element (`{int}`).

But this compiles without error:

```
template<typename FirstArg>
void foo(FirstArg x)
{
}

template<typename FirstArg, typename... RestOfArgs>
void foo(FirstArg x, RestOfArgs... y)
{
    foo(y...);
}

int main()
{
    foo<int, int, int>(5, 6, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is there ambiguity in the first case?

Why is there no ambiguity in the second case?

Comment: My assumption is that it has something to do with the fact that function's signature are its arguments, and that `<int>` and `<int>` are indistinguishable in one case, but in the other somewhy.

Comment: Look at [overload_resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), and [Function_template_overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading)

Comment: @Jarod42 I looked at it but still don't know the answer to my questions.

Comment: @rubix_addict: I agree that it is not obvious from the given links. I highlight the point in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

[The answer by @ZangMingJie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42063353/434551) answers the difference in behavior your are observing in your code.

I found it easier to understand the name resolution with the following change:

```
template<typename FirstArg>
void foo()
{
    printf("1\n");
}

template<typename FirstArg, typename SecondArg, typename... RestOfArgs>
void foo()
{
    printf("2\n");
    foo<SecondArg, RestOfArgs...>();
}

int main()
{
    foo<int, int, int>();
    return 0;
}
```

When two or more template parameters are used, the second function gets invoked. When one template parameter is used, the first function gets invoked.

Comment: This works and solves the problem of ambiguity but I still don't know why. My original question has not been answered yet.

Comment: @rubix_addict, I thought the answer by Zang did explain the issue.

Comment: @RSahu: I don't think so, as he explains, SFINAE on content of definition of the function would be used, which is wrong :-/

Answer (score 3):

In [Function template overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading)

There is lot of rules to tell which template function is more specialized (according to given parameters).

The point which makes

```
template<typename> void foo();
template<typename, typename...> void foo();
```

ambiguous for `foo<int>()`, but not

```
template<typename T> void foo(T);
template<typename T, typename... Ts> void foo(T, Ts...);
```

for `foo(42)` is the following:

> In case of a tie, if one function template has a trailing parameter pack and the other does not, the one with the omitted parameter is considered to be more specialized than the one with the empty parameter pack.

Comment: Wouldn't this sentence suggest that there shouldn't be any ambiguity in both cases? Well, the "trailing parameter pack" is kinda... ambiguous (pun intended) - it can apply to both "trailing template parameter pack" and "trailing function parameter pack".

Comment: I agree that it is not clear enough IMO, but "trailing"  won't apply to `template <typename Leading, typename Ts..., typename Trailing> void f(Leading, std::tuple<Ts...>, Trailing)` vs `template <typename B, typename A> void f(A, std::tuple<>, B)`. which is similar to your cases.

Comment: but in both of my cases parameter  packs are "trailing"

Comment: I meant that trailing parameters, apply to the parameter of the function, not of the template (which would make some in-coherency with above example).

Answer (score 1):

**Why is there ambiguity in the first case?**

`RestOfArgs` can be empty.

So `foo<int>` can be instantiated as:

```
template<int>
void foo()
{
}
```

and

```
template<int,>
void foo()
{
    foo<>();
}
```

both will compile, so it is ambiguous.

Actually `foo<>()` won't compile, but it fails in the next instantiation, so it doesn't matter.

**Why is there no ambiguity in the second case?**

`foo<int>(7)` can be instantiated as:

```
template<int>
void foo(int 7)
{
}
```

and

```
template<int>
void foo(int 7)
{
    foo();
}
```

but the second one is an error, because there are no foo taking no argument, so the only candidate is the first one, so there won't be ambiguous

Comment: Would you mind explaining [this example](http://ideone.com/ZQz8Le) as well? I've removed `foo` calls and it still compiles.

Comment: @yeputons sure, without recursive call, only VAARG template is used.

Comment: @yeputons, don't use SO as a consulting service. This is a good answer to your question. If you have other related questions, please post another question.

Comment: @ZangMingJie so in the second case the second foo overload is removed from the overload set due to SFINAE, right?

Comment: @rubix_addict I thought that as well (see my comments to two answers here), but looks like it's not the case (see my example). If you omit call to `foo` in the second overload, it still compiles when arguments are specified (yet unused), but does not when they are not.

Comment: @RSahu I should have been more specific. I believe that this post _does not fully answer the question_ asked by OP and can be significantly improved, so I'm asking for that. It shows one possible reason for the observed behavior, but even if that reason if removed, the behavior is still observed, see [my example](http://ideone.com/ZQz8Le).

Comment: You seems to say that overload is rejected according to definition/content of the function, which is wrong. Only the declarations are used to select overloads.