# Recursive Variadic Template Function - No ambiguity?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I am currently studying variadic templates, and as a small exercise to digest some of the stuff I had been reading about, I wrote a small function to output the names of all of its argument types:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename Next, typename... Rest>
std::string get_arg_types(Next next, Rest... rest)
{
    return std::string(typeid(Next).name()) + "\n" + get_arg_types(rest...);
}

template<typename Last>
std::string get_arg_types(Last last)
{
    return std::string(typeid(Last).name());
}

int main()
{
    float f = 0;
    double d = 0;
    int i = 0;

    std::cout << get_arg_types(f, d, i);

    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, this compiled using VC++ 12.0 and (seems to) work just fine.

I expected an error due to ambiguity between the overload when there is only one argument remaining, because I read that a template parameter pack can be empty/contain 0 arguments.

So my question is why does this work? How is the "potential ambiguity" resolved? Are the signature for both functions not identical with only 1 arg? I feel like I may have missed some important concept somewhere, because in my head the above example shouldn't compile, but obviously I am wrong.

Kind regards :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous call when recursively calling variadic template function overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063084/ambiguous-call-when-recursively-calling-variadic-template-function-overload) (Edit: the duplicate's question is slightly different but the answer does kinda cater to this...)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Thank you for the link, but I feel the answers for that question don't really tell me anything more than "in my example, there will be no ambiguity". I already know that. What I want to know is why (i.e. how is the potential ambiguity resolved)

Comment: Concerning the possible duplicate link of TrebuchetMS: This is what [Jarods answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234945/7478597) explains (in the yellow box): _if one function template has a trailing parameter pack and the other does not, the one with the omitted parameter is considered to be more specialized than the one with the empty parameter pack._ Doesn't this answer why it works for the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is problematic, but for a different reason. As noted in a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42234945/7478597) to the related question [Ambiguous call when recursively calling variadic template function overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42063084/ambiguous-call-when-recursively-calling-variadic-template-function-overload), the second overload in your code is considered more specialized. However, it should appear *before* the routine with the parameter pack. Compiling your code with `gcc` 8.2.1 or `clang` 6.0.1 gives an error like

```
variadic.cpp: In instantiation of ‘std::__cxx11::string get_arg_types(Next, Rest ...) [with Next = int; Rest = {}; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’:
variadic.cpp:7:67:   recursively required from ‘std::__cxx11::string get_arg_types(Next, Rest ...) [with Next = double; Rest = {int}; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
variadic.cpp:7:67:   required from ‘std::__cxx11::string get_arg_types(Next, Rest ...) [with Next = float; Rest = {double, int}; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
variadic.cpp:23:39:   required from here
variadic.cpp:7:67: error: no matching function for call to ‘get_arg_types()’
     return std::string(typeid(Next).name()) + "\n" + get_arg_types(rest...);
error: no matching function for call to ‘get_arg_types()
```

As you can see from the error, even when `get_arg_types` has a single parameter, the compiler picks up the first overload, which in turns call `get_arg_types` without arguments. A simple solution is to move the overload of `get_arg_types` with a single parameter before the routine with the template parameter pack, or add a declaration of the single-parameter `get_arg_types` before the general routine.

Alternatively, you could eliminate your specialization single-parameter of `get_arg_types` and add a specialization with 0 parameters:

```
std::string get_arg_types()
{
  return std::string();
}
```

Again, such a specialization should be put (or at least declared) before the template routine. Notice that with this second solution the output is slightly changed.